# Dask pivot_table with column type object vs column type category

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, dask-dataframe

I can't pivot a dask dataframe unless my object type columns are converted to categorical columns.

```
ValueError: 'columns' must be category dtype
```

I am having a hard time understanding why dask is requiring me to have a column's type be specifically a `category` instead of also accepting an `object (aka dtype('O') )`.

It works perfectly in pandas.